# Trash emptied but memory not cleared

Tags: osx, trash

I'm sure this question has been asked elsewhere, but try as I may I can't find the answer.

I had some particularly large files that I wanted to delete, so I dragged them to the trash and emptied the trash. The space has not been liberated on my hard drive, however. I think I remember that OSX keeps a temporary copy around for a bit.

Is there any way to force this space to be liberated now?

Comment: Maybe it helps : there is a SE community dedicated to Apple users ( https://apple.stackexchange.com/ ) , and your problem seems more OSX-specific, rather than Unix-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Unix won't clear the memory if the files are still 'in use', use **lsof | grep deleted** to show these, you can then truncate or kill the PIDs.